# How to handle an unauthorized ajax call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to figure out how to prevent a cors error from showing up in developer tools.  The way I get the cors error is when I am using an application but in another tab/window I log out of that application but then go back to the other tab and try to do work. Below is my ajax call.

```
function RemoveScholarshipRequest(id, name) {

    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the scholarship request for " + name + "?")) {
        var dataSource = $('#Pending').data('kendoGrid').dataSource;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("RemoveRequest", "Admin")',
            data: {id: id}
        }).done(function (response, data, xhr) {
            if (response.success) {
                dataSource.read();
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
            else if (!response.success) {
                if (response.responseText === "Not Authenticated")
                alert(response.responseText);
                console.log("error", data.status);
                //This shows status message eg. Forbidden
                console.log("STATUS: "+JSON.stringify(xhr.status));
            }
            }).fail(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                //window.location.href = "/forms/ScholarshipDisbursement/Admin/PendingRequests";
        });
    }
}
```

The controller action that the above ajax method calls is below:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RemoveRequest(string id)
    {
        if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, responseText = "Not Authenticated" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        if (User.IsInRole("Developer") || User.IsInRole("BannerAdmin"))
        {
            new ScholarshipRequestStore().DeleteScholarshipRequest(id);
            return Json(new { success = true, responseText = "Successfully deleted" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, responseText = "You are not an authorized user" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
    }
```

One way I get around the cors error is by putting AllowAnonymous on the method and then checking for authentication in the method itself but I don't really like that idea.  Is there another way of resolving this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow anonymous will not solve this, instead you need to send the allow origin header in your api. You can do this by enabling CORs in the startup class as follows

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add Cors
        services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader();
        }));

        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
        services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory("MyPolicy"));
        });

        ...
        ...
        ...
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure 
    //the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        // Enable Cors
        app.UseCors("MyPolicy");

        //app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        app.UseMvc();

        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
```

and then using the "Enable cors" attribute on your controller

```
[EnableCors("MyPolicy")]
[AllowAnonymous]
 [HttpPost]
public ActionResult RemoveRequest(string id)
```

read this for better idea https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Note: I have allowed any origin to talk to the API, you can specify whatever origin you want like "https://example.com"

Answer (score 0):

AllowAnonymous won't resolve a "cross-origin" request. The issue you are getting is due to tabbed browsing within your browser having a shared store of authenticated sessions. When you log out in tab 1, the session cookie is removed and then tab 2 is no longer authenticated. This is why AllowAnonymous "works" because without a current authenticated session, you're an anonymous user.

CORS, on the other hand, is when you allow calls to http://myservice.com to come from a different host like http://myclient.com. Anonymous access won't have any impact on that.